Как сделать стрелки для квадратных аналоговых часов?
Я пытаюсь сделать аналоговые часы, но квадратные. Проблема в создании стрелок. Ни в какую не получается создать стрелки.
    #card7 {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #C4C4C4;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
    }
    .line {
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px;
      background-color: #0000AA;
      font-size: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
    .turn {
      width: 40px;
      height: 35px;
      background-color: #C4C4C4;
      text-align: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 2px solid Black;
      display: flex;
    }
    .title {
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
    }
    .close {
      width: 40px;
      height: 35px;
      background-color: #C4C4C4;
      text-align: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 2px solid Black;
      display: flex;
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px 0px #FFFFFF, inset -3px -3px 0px 0px #939393;
    }
    #clockFace {
      width: 490px;
      height: 460px;
      margin: 7px 5px;
      background-color: #C4C4C4;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(149, 1, 1, 1), inset 0px 0px 0px 15px rgba(149, 1, 1, 1);
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    #clockFace::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #000;
    }
    #clockFace div {
      position: absolute;
      inset: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(calc(30deg * var(--i)));
    }
    #clockFace div p {
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(calc(-30deg * var(--i)));
    }
    .hour-hand {
      width: 8px;
      height: 20px;
      background: seagreen;
    }
    .minute-hand {
      width: 8px;
      height: 140px;
      background: seagreen;
    }
    .second-hand {
      width: 8px;
      height: 160px;
      background: seagreen;
    }
    .hour-hand,
    .minute-hand,
    .second-hand {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "ru">
    <div id="card7">
    <div class="line">
    <div class="turn">➖</div>
    <p class="title">Часы</p>
    <div class="close">▲</div>
    </div>
    <!--Часы-->
    <div id="clockFace">
    <div style="--i:1;">
    <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:2;">
    <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:3;">
    <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:4;">
    <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:5;">
    <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:6;">
    <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:7;">
    <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:8;">
    <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:9;">
    <p>9</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:10;">
    <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:11;">
    <p>11</p>
    </div>
    <div style="--i:12;">
    <p>12</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="minute-hand"></div>
    <div class="second-hand"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</html>


Селектор #clockFace div перебивает по специфичности классы стрелок, поэтому их настройки игнорируются.
В качестве решения можно

либо увеличить специфичность классов для стрелок,
либо изменить селектор для отметок часов
вынести стрелки из общего контейнера

Например: добавим класс для дивов ответственных за хранение меток часов, селектор вместо #clockFace div станет обычным селектором класса, и не будет влиять на элементы стрелок.
Кроме того, стрелки сами по себе были позиционированы не совсем корректно. Из-за того что отступ считается снизу, не нужно поднимать их в трансформе.


#card7 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #0000AA;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.turn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid Black;
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.close {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid Black;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px 0px #FFFFFF, inset -3px -3px 0px 0px #939393;
}

#clockFace {
  width: 490px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 7px 5px;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(149, 1, 1, 1), inset 0px 0px 0px 15px rgba(149, 1, 1, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#clockFace::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(calc(30deg * var(--i)));
}

.label p {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(calc(-30deg * var(--i)));
}

.hour-hand {
  width: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  background: seagreen;
}

.minute-hand {
  width: 8px;
  height: 140px;
  background: seagreen;
}

.second-hand {
  width: 8px;
  height: 160px;
  background: seagreen;
}

.hour-hand,
.minute-hand,
.second-hand {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
<div id="card7">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="turn">➖</div>
    <p class="title">Часы</p>
    <div class="close">▲</div>
  </div>
  <!--Часы-->
  <div id="clockFace">
    <div class="label" style="--i:1;">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:2;">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:3;">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:4;">
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:5;">
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:6;">
      <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:7;">
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:8;">
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:9;">
      <p>9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:10;">
      <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:11;">
      <p>11</p>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="--i:12;">
      <p>12</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="minute-hand"></div>
    <div class="second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>




Понял спасибо большое.
